# How to detect less than or greater than 90 degree edges(line) in an Image

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

In my project, I need to detect the roof of a house plan. For that, I have to use the front elevation of the blueprint. I'm planning to use open-cv HoughLines method. Using that I need to detect the roof of the house. Below I have attached the image of the house and my code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('lol.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 3)

lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,100)
count =0
for rho,theta in lines[0]:
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

    if( 20 < 180*theta/np.pi < 88):
        cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 255), 2)

    if (160 > 180 * theta / np.pi > 93):
        cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imwrite('detectP.jpg',img)
plt.imshow(img)
```

House plan I used.

[image]

Result obtained after executing the code,

[image]

As you can see the detection go through the entire image. I need it to detect only the line and draw the line on top of the angle line not entire image.

Comment: why should the algorithm detect the 0 degree line on the left top but not the ones on the bottom?

Comment: that's a mistake. the one in 0 degree isn't detecting. photoshop mistake.

Comment: `for rho,theta in lines[0]:` -- you're already iterating over the lines, and `theta` is the angle of the line. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: try sth like `if 20 < 180*theta/pi  < 70 plot the line; else don't plot the line`

Comment: @DanMašek what I want is, the lines which are marked in the last image. what i get is the 2nd image. simply I don't want the horizontal and vertical lines which doesn't have and angle

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HoughLinesP() function which is Probabilistic Hough Line Transform.
Visit https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html